# (VB.Net) BaseClass properties aren't displayed in DataGridView when data-binding

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, datagridview

I am trying to bind a DataGridView to a list of DerivedClass objects. The problem is that when I do so via `DataGridView.DataSource = New BindingList(Of DerivedClass)(myList)` only DerivedClass properties are shown (`Graf`) in DataGridView. I need all the properties (`Name`, `Details`, `Day`) to be shown. Is there a simple solution for this ?
Thank you very much for your input.

BaseClass:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseClass
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Details As String
    Public Property Day As DateTime
End Class
```

DerivedClass:

```
Public Class DerivedClass
    Inherits BaseClass
    Public Property Graf As Graf
End Class
```

Main Method:

```
Module MainModule
    Public myList As List(Of DerivedClass) = ...
    Sub Main()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = New BindingList(Of DerivedClass)(myList)
    End Sub
End Module
```

EDIT:
In fact the code above is significantly simplified. Here I provide futher details about the implementation, as It seems to be the source of the problem.

Interface 1

```
Public Interface IBaseInterface
    Property Name As String
    Property Detials As String
    Property Day As DateTime
End Interface
```

Interface 2

```
Public Interface ISample
    Inherits IBaseInterface
    Property Graf As Graf
End Interface
```

Abstract Class implementing IBaseInterface

```
  Public MustInherit Class BaseClass
        Implements IBaseInterface
        Public Property Name As String Implements IBaseInterface.Name
        Public Property Details As String Implements IBaseInterface.Detials
        Public Property Day As DateTime Implements IBaseInterface.Day
    End Class
```

Concrete Class Implementing ISample and inheriting from BaseClass

```
Public Class Sample
        Inherits BaseClass
        Implements ISample
        Public Property Graf As Graf Implements ISample.Graf
    End Class
```

Main Method

```
Module MainModule
    Public myList As List(Of ISample)
    Sub Main()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = New BindingList(myList)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Have you tried the other way `New BindingList(Of BaseClass)(myList)` ?

Comment: @AlexB. I have. It throws an InvalidCastException exception.

Comment: The very same problem occured when I tried to iterate over the DerivedClass properties via reflection. Only the Graf was obtained.

Comment: What does *only DerivedClass properties are shown in DataGridView* mean? That you see only the `Graf` property? That's not possible.

Comment: @Jimi Exactly. There is only one column "Graf".

Comment: Something else is at play here. I just tested your code with the `Graf` type changed to `Integer` and it worked exactly as expected, i.e. all four columns were displayed. Unless an exception is being thrown when a column is created for `Graf` because of the type, there must be something you're not telling us. Can you provide the implement for the `Graf` type?

Comment: Not possible: the `BaseClass` properties are part of the `DerivedClass` object. Double-check your implementation.

Comment: If you want to show all properties of Graf in your grid you have to flattern its properties to DerivedClass or you handle the `CellFormatting` event and populate the columns e.g. via getting all properties via reflection

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have edited the question appropriately to provide more details about the implementation. In fact classes do implement some interfaces as well, that may also cause some problems.

Comment: The issue is definitely the interfaces. If I create the `List` and `BindingList` against the `Sample` class then I see all four columns in the grid but, if I use the `ISample` interface, then I only see the one. Data-binding is based on `PropertyDescriptors` rather than actual properties so there must be something about inherited interfaces that doesn't propagate inherited properties. Maybe you need a custom `TypeDescriptor` or something. Not across all the details well-enough to know.

Comment: @Jimi Graf has only one property of String called Path.

Comment: Make a `List(Of Sample)` and a BindingList of the same type. `ISample` is not a class, you need a concrete implementation of the Interface.

Comment: Plus, you cannot have mixed data objects presented in a DataGridView, so a `List(Of ISample)` is not really useful here. You could have a generic method that acts as constructor for objects that can be derived from `ISample`, as the constraint (a Factory).

Comment: @Jimi I though of this solution as well, but I thought it is a better practice to code against interfaces. Apparantly there are still things I need to learn. Thank you very much for your input, this solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jimi suggested in comments I changed the list type from `ISample` to `Sample`, what solved the problem.